# Setting up Visual Studio web project shared on intranet

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2012

I just followed the instructions in this thread [Browse Web Site With IP Address Rather than localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14881515/browse-web-site-with-ip-address-rather-than-localhost) but now I can't even launch IIS express. Specifically, the error I got is "Unable to launch the IIS Express Web server".

Visual Studio Project settings:

```
Use Local IIS Web Server
Use IIS Express
Project Url:http://3.114.169.118:1407/
```

Application Config Code

```
<sites>
        <site name="WebSite1" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
            <application path="/">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\TestBillingApp\BillingApp\BillingApp" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:1407:3.114.169.118" />
            </bindings>
        </site>
```

Created acl in cmd

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://3.114.169.118:1407/ user=everyone
```

**Update:** I just noticed that if I browse to the ip in my browser right after launching, it's up and running. But it only runs for like 10 seconds, then I get the Unable to launch the IIS Express Web Server error, and it goes down.

Comment: Are these settings for your local development machine? Because that IP address appears to resolve to "n003-000-000-000.static.ge.com"

Comment: I fixed it by replacing the ip address with my machine name. your comment got me questioning that though which led me to the solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check that the IP address you are using is correct. Because the IP address listed appears to resolve to "n003-000-000-000.static.ge.com"

Comment: I swapped the IP Address with my computer name and it worked and was accessibly throughout the network. However, once I lost admin privileges, I could no longer launch my application. I was granted admin privileges again and deleted the old acl and created a new one with the definition http://*:1407/ user=everyone. I'm hoping it will now still work when I lose admin privileges? I was getting access denied before when I lost privileges.