# Bad Request - Invalid Hostname HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid. when i am using ngrok

Tags: ngrok

When I am using `ngrok` & run url given by ngrok with following configuration:

- my local url is : `localhost:8080/someexample`
- my `ngrok` url is : `http://f07d0862.ngrok.io/`

it show this error:

```sh
Bad Request - Invalid Hostname  HTTP Error 400.
```

Comment: Can you tell how are you generating the ngrok url?

Comment: Hey Sunny: can you mark the answer as correct ?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30535336/exposing-localhost-to-the-internet-via-tunneling-using-ngrok-http-error-400

Answer (score 182):

Your web server is rejecting the request since it has different hostname.

Try `ngrok http -host-header="localhost:8080"`

Comment: This works perfectly, and is also a perfect solution for developing with Facebook Messenger webhooks.

Comment: This answer is missing the quotation marks around the host-header value, and the colon, should be: `-host-header="localhost:8080"`

Comment: Please refer the following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30535336/exposing-localhost-to-the-internet-via-tunneling-using-ngrok-http-error-400

Comment: This is the command that worked for me is ngrok http -host-header=localhost 8080  Using the other command showed an error

FAILED TO COMPLETE TUNNEL CONNECTION

The connection to http://27900a3a1d5e.ngrok.io was successfully tunneled to your ngrok client, but the client failed to establish a connection to the local address host-header=localhost:33511.

Make sure that a web service is running on host-header=localhost:33511 and that it is a valid address.

The error encountered was: dial tcp: lookup host-header=localhost: no such host

Comment: I needed to use two leading dashes on ngrok 3.0.6: `--host-header="localhost:8080"`

Answer (score 40):

This is the solution you want.

```sh
ngrok http 8080 -host-header="localhost:8080"
```

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

```
ngrok http -host-header=localhost 8080
```

Answer (score 3):

For me it was this

```
ngrok.exe http https://localhost:44315 --host-header=localhost:44315
```

Answer (score 0):

If getting -o flag something error try with double **-**

ngrok http 8080 --host-header="localhost:8080"

Answer (score 0):

This command works for me(note the **double hyphen before host** keyword):

```
ngrok http --host-header=localhost 48333
```

Answer (score -2):

May be you should turn off your firewall.

That works for me.

Comment: Ngrok bypasses firewall restrictions, how should a firewall be a problem.