# The error encountered was: dial tcp [::1]:3000: getsockopt: connection refused

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ngrok

I am working on getting webhook to land in rails application. My rails server runs and I have already connected to ngrok and external application. But that errors to point out my application doesn't run.

`localhost:3000` runs and I can get webhooks to ngrok. What's the matter?

---

The connection to http://9xxxxxx5.ngrok.io was successfully tunneled to your ngrok client, but the client failed to establish a connection to the local address localhost:3000.

Make sure that a web service is running on localhost:3000 and that it is a valid address.

The error encountered was: dial tcp [::1]:3000: getsockopt: connection refused

---

After I see localhost:3000, rails application runs. Why that could not connect....

Here is the result `ps aux | grep ruby`.

```
user               63542   0.0  0.0  4306992     40 s000  S+    7:00PM   0:00.05 /Users/xxxxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.10.3/bin/fsevent_watch --format=otnetstring --latency 0.1 /Users/xxxxxx/Workspace/app/app/assets
user               63541   0.0  0.0  4306992     40 s000  S+    7:00PM   0:00.05 /Users/xxxxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.10.3/bin/fsevent_watch --format=otnetstring --latency 0.1 /Users/xxxxxx/Workspace/app/app/channels
user               63540   0.0  0.0  4298800     40 s000  S+    7:00PM   0:00.05 /Users/xxxxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.10.3/bin/fsevent_watch --format=otnetstring --latency 0.1 /Users/xxxxxx/Workspace/app/test/mailers/previews
user               63539   0.0  0.0  4306992     40 s000  S+    7:00PM   0:00.04 /Users/xxxxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.10.3/bin/fsevent_watch --format=otnetstring --latency 0.1 /Users/xxxxxx/Workspace/app/app/uploaders
user               63538   0.0  0.0  4306992     40 s000  S+    7:00PM   0:00.05 /Users/xxxxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.10.3/bin/fsevent_watch --format=otnetstring --latency 0.1 /Users/xxxxxx/Workspace/app/app/services
user               63537   0.0  0.0  4306992     40 s000  S+    7:00PM   0:00.05 /Users/xxxxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.10.3/bin/fsevent_watch --format=otnetstring --latency 0.1 /Users/xxxxxx/Workspace/app/app/models
user               63536   0.0  0.0  4306992     40 s000  S+    7:00PM   0:00.05 /Users/xxxxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.10.3/bin/fsevent_watch --format=otnetstring --latency 0.1 /Users/xxxxxx/Workspace/app/app/mailers
user               63535   0.0  0.0  4306992     40 s000  S+    7:00PM   0:00.05 /Users/xxxxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.10.3/bin/fsevent_watch --format=otnetstring --latency 0.1 /Users/xxxxxx/Workspace/app/app/jobs
user               63534   0.0  0.0  4306992     40 s000  S+    7:00PM   0:00.05 /Users/xxxxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.10.3/bin/fsevent_watch --format=otnetstring --latency 0.1 /Users/xxxxxx/Workspace/app/app/helpers
user               63533   0.0  0.0  4306992     40 s000  S+    7:00PM   0:00.05 /Users/xxxxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.10.3/bin/fsevent_watch --format=otnetstring --latency 0.1 /Users/xxxxxx/Workspace/app/app/controllers
user               63532   0.0  0.0  4298800     40 s000  S+    7:00PM   0:00.05 /Users/xxxxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.10.3/bin/fsevent_watch --format=otnetstring --latency 0.1 /Users/xxxxxx/Workspace/app/db
user               63531   0.0  0.0  4298800     40 s000  S+    7:00PM   0:00.06 /Users/xxxxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rb-fsevent-0.10.3/bin/fsevent_watch --format=otnetstring --latency 0.1 /Users/xxxxxx/Workspace/app/config/locales
user               64927   0.0  0.0  4258736    192 s002  R+    7:42PM   0:00.00 grep ruby
```

## Update

I have tried to kill last one. But I couldn't because process number is random every time like below:

[image]

And I could not connect ngrok still ....

Comment: Can you post the full backtrace errors from your rails server in your local terminal?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But I could not find any errors in rails server because this error may be occured by not connecting ngrok with rails.

Comment: what do you mean by `click localhost:3000` ?

Comment: type this in the terminal and paste your output in your question.  `ps aux | grep ruby`

Comment: @lacostenycoder Thanks so much. I have added the result in questions.

Comment: see my updated answer, but also, what server are you running locally? webrick or something else like thin, or unicorn?

Comment: Do you have a firewall perhaps blocking?  But maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30535336/exposing-localhost-to-the-internet-via-tunneling-using-ngrok-http-error-400

Comment: Thanks @lacostenycoder . I'll try to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @lascostenycoder

I'm so surprised that I could fix that after `sudo vi /etc/hosts`.
I had edited for other projects with MAMP. So I could not do that.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I actually thought of this yesterday but not sure why I didn't suggest to check that. I updated my answer since I should have mentioned that as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the port to your ngrok command, rails default local development is 3000

```
ngrok http 3000
```

Then you should be able to type your ngrok address in your browser

```
http://xxxxxx.ngrok.io/
```

The only way I'm able to reproduce your error is to stop my rails server, then when I try to open the ngrok url I get your error.  So this means either your server is NOT running or ngrok can't connect to it.

#### UPDATE 2

Make sure you don't have anything going on in `/etc/hosts` that could cause a problem.

#### Update

Make sure you don't have any rogue ruby processes running.  Based on your updated comment run this to kill them all

```
ps aux | grep ruby | awk '{print $2}' |  xargs kill -9
```

Or try to see if spring is the problem:

```
spring status
spring stop
```

Then check and make sure everything has been killed, then start over from step 1.

```
ps aux | grep ruby
```

It may be something specific to your app/config?  So try to kill all your running rails servers, if you're not sure, restart your machine.  Then go to a new project folder, just add a new rails app and once it's running, try ngrok again and see if it works.  Also make sure you use http and https in your ngrok command.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I run `ngrok http 3000` and then I checked http://xxxx.ngrok.io on display in Terminal. But that would not work.

Comment: @k10a is your rails server running in another terminal before you run `ngrok` ? And of course the `xxxx` is fake, you'll get a new random hash prefix each time you run a new `ngrok`

Comment: Yeah I launched rails server before ngrok and I replace from xxxx to own ngrok url.

Comment: @k10a how are you launching rails server?

Comment: Thanks for your help. In termnial, `$ rails s` as usual.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I really appreciate that but I could not connect after trying which you told me...