# Unable to launch the IIS Express Web server.with VS2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, iis-express

i was working with MVC related projects when i added a new MVC projects all of a sudden i am getting pop error Unable to launch the IIS Express Web server, detailed error is like port 8080 is already being used by process IIS Express. I dont know why all of a sudden i am getting this error and now i am not able to launch MVC sites itself. Some times error is like Unable to launch the IIS Express Web server ,portxxxxx(project specific) is already in use.I wonder how all of a sudden it came

Googlin issue doesnot work , all of sudden why??it seems some serious issue with VS
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18454751/unable-to-launch-the-iis-express-web-server-error)

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15873126/unable-to-launch-the-iis-express-web-server)

Comment: Try to change port number in project property/web/projecturl

Comment: @theLaw nothing works here

Answer (score 0):

I dont know this will help others , i made it work by creating separate solution and created everything from scratch and got worked.Still wonder what happened .Good day cheers