# Visual studio 2015 IIS Express

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, iis-express

I try to start ASP.NET MVC 5 solution on my work station, it fails: "Unable to launch the IIS Express Web server" and that is all, But on my home station it works perfectly. Also I try to run new ASP.NET MVC 5 solution on work station and it starts with IIS Express!

I also try to "Create Virtual Directory" in solution properties.

What also I need to change or to see? I can't understand why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Unable to launch the IIS Express Web server" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18454751/unable-to-launch-the-iis-express-web-server-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 -> Update 3, and Install VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2 on my work station as well as I have on my home station. And all become work perfect!