# IISExpress crash upon debug start

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

When i try to start my ASP.NET application from VS (2015 or 2017) it just crash with no error in output window.

> The program '[8464] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

But Windows Event log says this:

> The Module name ManagedEngineV4.0_32bit path C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\webengine4.dll returned an error from registration.  The data is the error.

I have no more ideas about how to fix this.
I've tried to reinstall VS, IIS, even tried to remove .net framework, change IIS settings from 32 to 64bit but no luck so far.

Any chance someone experienced similar error and found the solution? :)

P.S. 
Extended error log:

> - System
>
>   - Provider
>
>   [ Name]  IIS Express
>
>   - EventID 2293
>
>   [ Qualifiers]  49152
>
>   Level 2
>
>   Task 0 
>      Keywords 0x80000000000000
>
>   - TimeCreated 
>       [ SystemTime]  2017-06-06T20:47:56.693031400Z
>   - EventRecordID 7271
>   - Channel Application
>   - Computer PC
>   - Security
> - EventData
>
>   ManagedEngineV4.0_32bit
>     C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\webengine4.dll
>     2BEE0CC0
>
> ---
>
> Binary data:
>
> In Words
>
> 0000: C00CEE2B
>
> In Bytes
>
> 0000: 2B EE 0C C0               +î.À

Comment: Is your application using MVC 4?

Comment: Did you enable 32-bit application to true in your app pool settings ?

Comment: MVC 5.

Yeah, i've tried 32/64 switch at app pool settings. it just provide this error instead:
>The Module name ManagedEngineV4.0_64bit path C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\webengine4.dll returned an error from registration.  The data is the error.

Also i've tried to create NEW black MVC Application with single View and Model - it also crash upon start.

Thanks for your replies!

Comment: can you check if your Asp.Net 4.6 have been checked in "Turn windows features on and off" under IIS -> World wide web services -> application development features  ?

Comment: ehm, i'm on Windows 10  Anniv Update, and it worked before, just something happend:)

Comment: Is that yes or no ?

Comment: That is what i don't have IIS under Turn Windows features on and off" :) i'm using IISExpress.

Comment: In event log, right click on the error and choose "Copy->Copy Details as Text". Then paste that in your question. What you have typed above is incomplete.

Comment: @LexLi, i've extended my error with detailed log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After couple of days spent trying to solve the problem, i didn't succeed, so here is quick workaround:

1. Uninstall of IISExpress v10
2. Install IISExpress v8

And everything works just fine

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old thread, but this has been killing me today. And since this is pretty much teh top thread on any search for the error, i decided to add this.

taken from here
["Unable to launch the IIS Express Web server" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18454751/unable-to-launch-the-iis-express-web-server-error)

1. Delete folder IISExpress from "My Documents"
2. Load your project again, it will create IISExpress folder again with updated configuration
3. Check IISExpress folder has sufficient permissions to read-write the configuration file
4. Load project again and Run IISExpress. It should work.

I didn't need to check any permissions or anything, just deleting and reloading the project was enough for IIS to behave itself and i could get back to some debugging fun.

Cheers

Comment: To add further details to this very relevant answer, double check whether your documents are synced to onedrive or not, and if they are onedrive needs to be running and syncing changes.

Comment: The other problem I actually had was how Windows 10 has enabled case sensitive directories. My route was defined as "/account/login" and the controller was named "AccountController" which I believe was giving the static file error.

Comment: `C:\Users\myusername\Documents` had an `IISExpess`, but deleting it didn't fix the issue. Then I realized actually there's another `IISExpess` folder in `C:\Users\myusername\OneDrive\Documents` where `Documents` was not in English, but in my system language - Russian, while there was yet another folder 'Documents' in English. Deleting the folder did it for me.

Comment: Thank you @Artemious, Documents\IISExpress was indeed in my company's OneDrive account folder.

Answer (score 0):

We encountered this same problem and event viewer error using IIS. For us the problem was we were modifying `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Aspnet.config` to apply [some garbage collection improvements](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/middle-ground-between-server-and-workstation-gc/), and ended up with a typo in the XML.

So not related to IIS Express, but thought I'd mention it for others who find this post when searching for the error message:

> The Module name ManagedEngineV4.0_64bit path
>   C:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\webengine4.dll
>   returned an error from registration.  The data is the error.