# Unable to launch the IIS Express Web server on specific project in vs 2015

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, iis, visual-studio-2015, iis-express

[image: See below error Message]

I have created new project and run, it was build successfully after that through an error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18454751/unable-to-launch-the-iis-express-web-server-error

Comment: Thanks @chidambaram

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had same issue occured and i fixed this issue by just remove the "applicationhost.config" file from your `Project directory` -> `.vs` folder -> `config` folder -> remove the `applicationhost.config` and clean & build project and run your project. It will successfully run your project

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same issue by creating virtual directory (Solution Explorer > Right Click on Project > Web > Create Virtual Directory and ticking 'Override application root URL'

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue and was able to fix it by updating the port number. In Solution Explorer --> Right Click and select Properties --> Web tab update the port number. I.e. My previous port was 57860 and I changed it to 57862. It fixed my issue.

[image]

**You can also fix this by closing IISExpress.exe in Task Manager --> Details tab simple.**

[image]