# Can't connect to IIS Express in VS2019 using IP Address

Tags: visual-studio-2019, iis-express

I'm trying to connect to my PC through my phones with IP Address and I have been followed these 2 posts:

[Browse Web Site With IP Address Rather than localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14881515/browse-web-site-with-ip-address-rather-than-localhost)

[Can't connect to IIS Express using IP Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14042271/cant-connect-to-iis-express-using-ip-address)

I have tried with many `<bindings>`

[image]

My Inbound rules:

[image]

`netsh` command with VS2019 run as admin but none of that work. On my PC, localhost run fine but `http://192.168.1.14:44375` is not working.

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html

Comment: I'm currently using conveyor as an alternative method

Answer (score 1):

steps :

1- check the IP in the listen list using the below command

```
netsh http show iplisten
```

2- in case the IP is not listed , then use the below command to add it

```
netsh http add iplisten 192.168.1.17
```

3- run F5 the visual studio now after you set your appURL

Please mark as best answer incase your problem has been solved